# Drag and drop problem with e.dataTransfer: weird behavior in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, filelist

I'm having a good time trying to solve the weird behavior of my drag and drop in Chrome. There's no problem when I add files by clicking, the problem is when I drop them. When I drag and drop files sometimes works and sometimes fails. Checking out the problem, I realized that in certain occasions the `e.dataTransfer.files` has a non empty FileList and works, but sometimes it doesn't, even when I'm selecting the same bunch of files. And sometimes, it shows a FileList with just one object even though I'm trying to add more than one file of PDF extension, and that only File object has no extension.

Here's the code...

```
    const handleDrag = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.type === "dragenter" || e.type === "dragover") {
            setDragActive(true);
        } else if (e.type === "dragleave") {
            setDragActive(false);
        }
    };

    // triggers when file is dropped
    const handleDrop = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        setDragActive(false);
        if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files[0]) {
            await props.handleFilesToUpload(e.dataTransfer.files, props.filesToUpload, props.setFilesToUpload)
            setDragActive(true)
        }
        e.dataTransfer.value = ""
        
    };

    // triggers when file is selected with click
    const handleChange = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setDragActive(false);
        if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
            await props.handleFilesToUpload(e.target.files, props.filesToUpload, props.setFilesToUpload)
            setDragActive(true)
        }
        e.target.value = ""
    };

    // triggers the input when the button is clicked
    const onButtonClick = (e) => {
        if (e.type === "click") {
            inputRef.current.click();
            setDragActive(true);            
        }
    };

    const onModalClose = () => {
        setDragActive(false)
        props.handleClose()
    }

return 

...
 <Grid item>
    <form id={styles["form-file-upload"]} onDragEnter={handleDrag} onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
    <input ref={inputRef} type="file" id={styles["input-file-upload"]} accept="application/pdf" multiple={true} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} onDragEnter={handleDrag}/>
    <label id={styles["label-file-upload"]} htmlFor="input-file-upload" className={dragActive ? "drag-active" : ""}>
          <div>
             <button className={styles.uploadButton} onDragEnter={handleDrag} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} onClick={e => onButtonClick(e)}>     
             <ThemeProvider theme = {theme} >
              <PictureAsPdfIcon fontSize='large' sx={{ pb: '10px', color: '#929395' }} />
               <Typography variant='h6' fontWeight='bold' color='#5F5F5F' sx={{ mb: '10px' }}>
                    Seleccionar archivos para cargar
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant='body1' color='#929395'>
              O arrastrar y soltar, copiar y pegar archivos.
              </Typography>
            </ThemeProvider>                                         
          </button>
       </div>
      </label>
{dragActive && <div id={styles["drag-file-element"]} onDragEnter={handleDrag} onDragLeave={handleDrag} onDragOver={handleDrag} onDrop={handleDrop} onClick={e => onButtonClick(e)}></div>}
   </form>
</Grid>
...
```

I want to figure out what could be wrong to approach the solution.

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by Chrome. I tried in Firefox, and everything works fine.